# Prisma thinks that this object isnt in my schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

I added a new value "expectedValue" to my schema, after creating many records, however i made it null-able so i didnt think it would be a problem:

```
model Procedure {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  stepNumber  Int
  step        String
  expectedValue String?
  testCaseRef TestCase @relation(fields: [TestCaseId], references: [id])
  TestCaseId  Int
}
```

and now when i try to add a record for the expectedValue element, it cant seem to find it.

I can see that it exists in my database because im looking at it in a database tool (tablePLus)

```
const testCaseCreated = await prisma.TestCase.create({
       data: {
         name: '',
         description: '',
         Procedure: {
           create: [
             {
               stepNumber: 1,
               step: 'add a prof',
               expectedValue: 'with vals'
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             }
           ]
         },
         tags: {
           create: [
             {
               tag: {
                 connectOrCreate: {
                   where: {
                     tagName: 'create'
                   },
                   create: {
                     tagName: 'create'
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
           ]
         },
         TestCase_TestSuite: {
           create: [
             {
               testSuite: {
                 connect: {
                   id: 86
                 }
               }
             }
           ]
         }
       }
     })
```

**the error im getting is:** Unknown arg `expectedValue` in data.Procedure.create.0.expectedValue for type ProcedureCreateWithoutTestCaseRefInput. Did you mean `select`? Available args:

```
type ProcedureCreateWithoutTestCaseRefInput {
  stepNumber: Int
  step: String
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by manually writing something in the expected values column on my database viewer
and now prisma can find it,
maybe its a bug in prisma.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).